# Custom status in Mantis Bug Tracker

Tags: bug-tracking, mantis, bug-tracker

I want to add a custom status to Mantis Bug tracker called "On Hold".  Following some blogs I found online, I added the following lines to config_local.php:

```
$g_status_enum_string = '10:new,20:feedback,30:acknowledged,40:confirmed,50:assigned,55:onhold,80:resolved,90:closed';
$g_status_colors['onhold'] = '#cceedd';
$s_status_enum_string = '10:new,20:feedback,30:acknowledged,40:confirmed,50:assigned,55:onhold,80:resolved,90:closed';
```

However, when I go to assign this status to a bug, it displays as @55@ in the drop down.

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [Mantis reference on customising status values](https://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master/en-US/Admin_Guide/html/admin.customize.status.html):

Define a constant to map the new status to.In a new file custom_constants_inc.php in the main mantisbt directory:

`<?php define ( 'TEST', 60 ); ?>`

Define the language strings required. This may need to be defined in several languages.In a new file custom_strings_inc.php in the main mantisbt directory:

```
<?php
$s_status_enum_string = '10:new,20:feedback,30:acknowledged,40:confirmed,50:assigned, 60:to be tested,80:resolved,90:closed';
$s_to_be_tested_bug_button = "Issue Ready to Test";
$s_to_be_tested_bug_title = "Set Issue Ready to Test"; 
$s_email_notification_title_for_status_bug_to_be_tested = "The following issue is ready TO BE TESTED.";
?>
```

Define any configurations required.In the existing file config_inc.php in the main mantisbt directory:

```
$g_status_enum_string = '10:new,20:feedback,30:acknowledged,40:confirmed,50:assigned, 60:to be tested,80:resolved,90:closed'; # Status color additions
$g_status_colors['to be tested'] = '#ACE7AE';
```

Add the status to any workflow defined in config_inc.php.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Making the changes you suggested appears to have fixed the problem.

Comment: @Xenos - that link is outdated, but not sure why I linked to mantisforge ... update link to mantisbt.org, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using MantisBT version 2.1.0 and had the same problem. The fix for me was to move the files `custom_constants_inc.php` and `custom_strings_inc.php` from the main mantisbt directory to the config directory.